# LibreOffice - How to create a file dialog via python macro?

Tags: python, macros, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a **standard file dialog to save a pdf** via a python macro. I've tried to write some code based on this outdated documentation: [wiki.openoffice.org](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python) but LibreOffice crashes after execution:

```
import os
import uno
import sys
import traceback
from com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.TemplateDescription import FILESAVE_SIMPLE

def file_dialog():
    try:
        oCtx = uno.getComponentContext()
        oServiceManager = oCtx.getServiceManager()

        oFilePicker = oServiceManager.createInstanceWithArgumentsAndContext(
                'com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FilePicker',
                (FILESAVE_SIMPLE,),
                oCtx
            )

        oFilePicker.Title = 'Export as'

        #oDisp = oFilePicker.Text

        oFilePicker.execute()

    except:
        pass
        #oDisp = traceback.format_exc(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

At the end I need to pass the selected path to write the document, but `oDisp = oFilePicker.Text` returns: `(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>`. Moreover is there a way to set the file type?

Does anyone have experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

I used [Xray](http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html) on the oFilePicker object.  There are a couple of interesting methods called setCurrentFilter and appendFilterGroup.  Just based on the names, they might be used to filter what file types are visible.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to use them.

Also with Xray, I determined that Text is not a method or property of the oFilePicker object.  I'm not sure what the code snippet is trying to do there?  If retrieve the filepath, 1) that needs to be done after the .execute and 2) the selected filepath is stored as an array of strings, so the path has to be pulled out of the array.  Most of my work in OpenOffice is in StarBasic; below is a working example in Basic of printing the filepath selected by the user:

```
Sub TestFilePicker
    oFilePickerDlg = createUnoService( "com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FilePicker" )
    oFilePickerDlg.setTitle("My test title")

    If oFilePickerDlg.execute() > 0 Then
        Print ConvertFromURL(oFilePickerDlg.Files(0))
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lyrl +1, but unfortunately I'm searching for a python solution.

Comment: Move the `oDisp = ` line to *after* the `.execute` line.  This I am 100% sure of.  Then change the `.Text` to `.Files(0)` - this part I'm a little unsure of, I'm not sure how python calls arrays.  But surely you, as a python user, will understand the intention is to assign the first entry in the array named `Files` to the variable `oDisp` and will know the correct python code.

Answer (score 1):

Answer given and accepted (because the question was cross posted!) [here](http://www.libreoffice-forum.de/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=15118):

```
import uno
from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue

#shortcut:
createUnoService = (
        XSCRIPTCONTEXT
        .getComponentContext()
        .getServiceManager()
        .createInstance 
                    )

def pypdf_test():

    desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
    doc = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

    # filter data
    fdata = []
    fdata1 = PropertyValue()
    fdata1.Name = "SelectPdfVersion"
    fdata1.Value = 1
    fdata2 = PropertyValue()
    fdata2.Name = "Quality"
    fdata2.Value = 100
    fdata.append(fdata1)
    fdata.append(fdata2)

    args = []
    arg1 = PropertyValue()
    arg1.Name = "FilterName"
    arg1.Value = "writer_web_pdf_Export"
    arg2 = PropertyValue()
    arg2.Name = "FilterData"
    arg2.Value = uno.Any("[]com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue", tuple(fdata) )
    args.append(arg1)
    args.append(arg2)
    fileurl = FilePicker()
    if fileurl:        
        doc.storeToURL( fileurl, tuple(args) )

def FilePicker(path=None, mode=1):
    """
    Datei öffnen:  `mode in (0, 6, 7, 8, 9)`
    Datei Schreiben `mode in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10)`
    see: ('''http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/
            namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1ui_1_1
            dialogs_1_1TemplateDescription.html''' )
    """

    filepicker = createUnoService( "com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.OfficeFilePicker" )
    if path:
        filepicker.setDisplayDirectory(path )
    filepicker.initialize( ( mode,) )
    if filepicker.execute():
        return filepicker.getFiles()[0]
```

Comment: Notified Karolus - he agrees. I'll accept and upvote your answer, if you explain the code a bit more, espacially for not german users **here**.

Comment: Explaining what?  
  
Your question was "Howto call built-in `FileDialog`, for a PDF export.
This code shows the setup of PDF attributes and a filter, calls the `FileDialog` and returns the name given (if not cancelled).

This version was written for LibreOffice, but works in Apache OpenOffice, too.

Comment: This is not a forum, explaining how the code works is good practice here.  Quote: `We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.`

Comment: I think it's rude not to give reference if doing a cross post. How many other sites/forums you asked without pointing it out?  
Code is Python = readable English.  
If you don't understand something ask.

Comment: Don't take it personal -  **your code includes german language**, please see the `FilePicker()` function. Again - it would be really nice **for other users here** to comment the code at least, see the stackoverflow rules in my quote above. If that's too complicated for you, I could edit your answer.